# What does "unshackle an entire swath of the human population" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning

While not a panacea, this blast of cutting-edge, twenty-first-century technology offers real promise as a way to help unshackle an entire swath of the human population

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Just take the phrase word by word, each word has its usual meaning: *unshackle* = 'set free'; *entire* = 'whole'; *swath* = 'large quantity (e.g., of hay)', and then put them together.

Comment: Metaphorically, it's supposed that vast swathes of the human population are "shackled" (to the daily grind of going to work to do a boring job, for example). This new technology (AI-powered robots, for example) might be able to handle the boring stuff, enabling many people to do something different (be artistically creative with all that "newly-available" time, or starve for lack of money to buy food, depending on your level of optimism).

Comment: Is your confusion over the meaning of one or more individual words, or the meaning behind everything? You need to provide more context. The sentence on its own doesn't indicate what people might be unshackled *from*.

Answer (score 1):

It means the author is a terrible writer:

A *swath* is a section of hay or grass cut down by a single pass of the scythe, and metaphorically, a large quantity or number.

*Unshackle* means "remove the shackles from", i.e. the steel constraints used on a prisoner or slave, and metaphorically, free or liberate anyone.

Put them together, they form a terrible mixed metaphor intended to convey "free a lot of people".

Throw in "panacea", "blast", and "cutting-edge" (all unrelated metaphors), you have an almost irrebuttable case for never reading this author again ever.

**Edit:** A commenter adds that this "explains why the meaning is opaque to the OP. Mixed metaphors are bad precisely because they have no continuity—and as a result, readers can't make sense of them as elements in a longer, cohesive narrative."

I regret not emphasizing this point myself.  Metaphors convey meaning as narrative.  They create a "picture", which the reader can see and understand.

There is a Polish expression that translates as "Not my circus, not my monkeys" and that strikes me as an almost perfect metaphor.  "This laughable, boisterous mess is not being conducted under my auspices, and therefore its filthy unruly destructive participants are not my responsibility."  The metaphor is pure, and therefore easily comprehended, even when brought into a foreign culture and language.

A mixed metaphor requires you to understand the content of the sentence in order to interpret the text of the sentence, which makes it almost useless.

> "While not a medication that can cure or prevent every medical ailment, this sudden movement of fluid carrying the sharp part of a knife representing technology between 2001 and 2101 has signed a binding agreement to remove manacles from a group of human being mown down by a grass-cutting implement of some sort."
>
> "Uh, what?"
>
> "Just translating what you said into English."

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it very neatly explains why the meaning is opaque to the OP. Mixed metaphors are bad precisely because they have no continuity—and as a result, readers can't make sense of them as elements in a longer, cohesive narrative.

Comment: FWIW, this is from a book authored by two Wall Street Journal reporters and published by a highly reputable publisher.

Comment: While explaining mixed-metaphor issues is useful, opening your answer by saying the meaning of the phrase is that the author is terrible makes your answer terrible.  That's not the meaning of the phrase, as your answer later explains, so saying so just adds to the level of confusion involved here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- not everyone who has a good reputation deserves a good reputation.

Comment: I think it would be better to reserve judgment until you have read the book - or at least the actual quote in its context.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- well, I would hate to be judged as a writer by the most graceless sentence I have ever written (although if I were, I would still score better than *this*); however, I would like to draw people attention to the important implication of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**swath** [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/swath)

The figurative use of **swath** has nonphysical senses as well, as in the term "a significant swath of the population believes..."

My sense of an entire swath = a whole lot of the population!

As in:

> 2017   Teen Vogue 19 No. 1. 112/1   Labels like ‘straight’ and
>   ‘gay’..are starting to feel too narrow, overlooking an entire swath of
>   sexuality.

and

> as a way to help unshackle (free) an entire swath ( a whole bunch of
>   folks) of the human population.